# Default type parameters in scala

Tags: scala, type-parameter

i have this trait

```
trait Extractor extends Mapping[Node]
```

what's the simplest way to change it to take a type parameter with a default value

```
trait Extractor[T] extends Mapping[**T if given else Node**]
```

other similar questions involves some irrelevant details about upper and lower type bounds

Comment: @flavian yeah but suppose the types i'm intending to set for the Extractor are not related by any means to class `Node` , so upper and lower bounds are in applicable in this case , or is there something that fits ?

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to overload `Extractor` to be of kind `*` and of kind `* -> *`. Overloading is usually best avoided, so instead I'd recommend,

```
scala> trait Mapping[T]
defined trait Mapping

scala> trait Node
defined trait Node

scala> trait Extractor[T] extends Mapping[T]
defined trait Extractor

scala> type NodeExtractor = Extractor[Node]
defined type alias NodeExtractor

scala> val ne = new NodeExtractor {}
ne: NodeExtractor = $anon$1@1ebdcc9a
```

If `Extractor[Node]` is the common case, then you could optimize for that and do something like this,

```
scala> trait ExtractorT[T] extends Mapping[T]
defined trait ExtractorT

scala> type Extractor = ExtractorT[Node]
defined type alias Extractor

scala> val ne = new Extractor {}
ne: Extractor = $anon$1@3d70fe39
```